# Where is the parameter coming from?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, arrow-functions

```
function createMathOperation(operator) {
  console.log(operator); //(augend, addend) => augend + addend
  return (value, other) => {
    return operator(value, other)
  }
}

const add = createMathOperation((augend, addend) => augend + addend)

add(1,2)//3
```

I found the above function definition from `lodash`. I am trying to understand it but to no avail.

Right inside `createMathOperation`, I try to log `operator` and this is the value

```
(augend, addend) => augend + addend
```

I guess `value` and `other` is `1` and `2` but how?

And how `return operator(value, other)` works when `operator` is `(augend, addend) => augend + addend`

Can anyone convert it to longer human readable form for a better understanding instead?

Comment: The crux of this is that in JS functions are objects and these objects can be passed around in just the same way as any other first class object.

Comment: Welcome to higher order functions. You're near the point of no return be careful: once you go in much further you can't go back.

Comment: @JaredSmith, he says, with a wiiide grin ...

Comment: @user633183 yup, posting the question at all means it's probably already too late. On to functors!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the essence of functional programming you can pass in a function, return a function, and call the function you received as a parameter:

```
function createMathOperation(operator) {
  console.log(operator); // This is a the function that performs the computation 
  // We return a new function (using arrow syntax) that receives 2 arguments and will call the original operator we passed in to createMathOperation
  // The code inside this function is not executed here, the function is not invoked. 
  // The caller can take the returned function and executed 0-n times as they wish. 
  return (value, other) => { 
    // when we invoke add this is the code that gets called and the arguments we pass to add end up in value and other
    console.log("Getting ready to compute " + value + " operator " + other); 
    return operator(value, other) // since operator is a function we just invoke it as we would any other function with the two arguments we got from whoever called us.
  }
}

// add will contain the wrapped function that has our extra console.log 
const add = createMathOperation((augend, addend) => augend + addend)

// The 'Getting ready ...' text has not been printed yet, nobody invoked the function that was returned yet, the next line will do so.
console.log(add(1,2)) 
// will output:
// Getting ready to compute 1 operator 2
// 3
```

A note on `=>` is just syntactic sugar over a `function` expression, it has extra semantics around `this`, but for this example, `(augend, addend) => augend + addend` is equivalent to `function (augend, addend){ return  augend + addend; }`

Comment: In your comments `We return a new function (using arrow syntax) that receives 2 arguments`. Which means `return (value,other) => {...}` is still only a function declaration right?

Comment: Yup, it's a function expression, it represents a new function that will be returned. The code inside will not be executed until you actually call `add`

Answer (score 1):

createMathOperation returns function, which adds two numbers. Here's more readable version:

```
function createMathOperation(fn) {
  console.log(fn);
  return function(value, other){
    return fn(value, other);
  };
}

const add = createMathOperation(function (augend, addend) {
  return augend + addend;
});

add(1,2)//3
```

I renamed 'operator' to 'fn' to make it less confusing (syntax highlighting colored it blue for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

Your code in good old JS would look like:

```js
var createMathOperation = function(operator) {
  // operator is scope-locked within this operation wrapper
  console.log('operator:', operator);
  return function(value, other) {
    // The wrapper returns an anonymous function that acts as a call-wrapper
    // for your original function
    console.log('value:', value);
    console.log('other:', other);
    return operator(value, other)
  }
}

var add = createMathOperation(function(augend, addend) {
  // This is what is being called at line 9 - return operator(value, other)
  return augend + addend;
});

console.log('result 1+2:', add(1,2));
```

In general i don't see much use to all of this, you could just do `const add = (a, v) => a + v;` and have the same result.

Comment: The original body of `createMathOperation` is in much longer form which to transform and handle all kinds of `undefined` values. I've removed them as they are just noise for my objective

Comment: I see, in that case that wrapper makes sense.